# Dart - how _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> convert to Map<String, dynamic>?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I use [package dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) in my flutter app. A get response from my api question.
`response.data` get type  `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`. I need convert this value to `Map<String, dynamic>`. I tried many options but this does not work.

I have no way to change the server response. Any advice?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic>.from(yourData)
```

Comment: This works, but it shouldn't be necessary and is wasteful.

Comment: Is not wasteful when returning a ``Map`` from a function. returning a ``_InternalLinkedHashMap`` in place of ``Map`` one gets an error:  ``A value of type 'LinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be returned from method 'predict' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'.`` Using ``Map<String, dynamic>.from(yourData)`` allows this return.

Comment: @StuckInPhD Your example use different parameterized types, so a conversion is necessary.  When the parameterized types are the same, as presented in the original question, a conversion is wasteful by creating an unnecessary copy.

Comment: I was getting a map from the Java side sent into the dart side, I had to do `Map<String, dynamic>.from(call.arguments as Map<Object?, Object?>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been trying to cast it for the last 45 minutes and you saved my life :D

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to do any conversion between `_InternalLinkedHashMap<K, V>` and `Map<K, V>`: the former is already a subtype of the latter.

```dart
void main() async {
  final map = <String, int>{};
  print(map.runtimeType);
  print(map is Map<String, int>);
}
```

prints:

```
_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>
true
```

([`Map`'s default constructor is a *factory* constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/Map/Map.html) that constructs a `LinkedHashMap`. `LinkedHashMap`'s default constructor is also a factory constructor, and the implementation for the Dart VM constructs and returns an internal `_InternalLinkedHashMap` object.)

---

Note that this is true only when `_InternalLinkedHashMap<K, V>` uses the same `K` and `V` as `Map`.  If they are parameterized on *different* types then you will need to perform an explicit conversion, but that's *not* the situation asked in *this question*.

Comment: If this was true we wouldn't get an error.

Comment: @DanielVilela Please show me the error.  All errors  that I have seen are cases where `_InternalLinkedHashMap` and `Map` are parameterized on *different* types, which is a different situation than what is asked in this question.  If you think what I wrote is not true, then run the code and show me different output.

Comment: Now the answer of @diegoveloper worked here. But for me this error ocurred when i worked with cloud functions for firebase and meilisearch. My response was this _linkedHashMap thing and i couldn't make a fromJson() from it, where i expected a Map<string, dynamic>. It threw an error and brought me here to stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure, diegoveloper's answer is necessary when `_InternalLinkedHashMap` and `Map` are parameterized on *different* types, which I suspect is what happened to you (and which is why I wanted to see your exact error message).  Using `Map.from` is unnecessary when they are parameterized on the *same* types.

Comment: This is the error: flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: As I suspected, you are describing a different issue than what this question is asking about. `T<dynamic, dynamic>` is not the same as `T<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Anyway, my point is that your initial statement "If this was true we wouldn't get an error" is an unfair claim.  My answer *is* true, and it solves the original question.

Comment: Hmm true.. i changed my json to <dynamic, dynamic> and it worked. I thought it was another thing so you are right.

Comment: But i mean, isn't this stupid? <string, dynamic> is more specific than <dynamic, dynamic>.. so shouldn't it be taken care of?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` can take any type for a key.  `Map<String, dynamic>` can take only `String`s as keys.  Therefore `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` is not a more specific type of `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Hmm i changed both in my head. You are correct.

Comment: @DanielVilela lifesaver <3

Answer (score 6):

How I do it, is I converts the _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> to a HashMap using

```
var map = HashMap.from(value) // value is _InternalLinkedHashMap <dynamic, dynamic>
```

From here I can get the Class Method to convert the map to my object so that I can use it in the code, like this

```
User.fromJson(map) //  this return User object
```

You can generate Dart Model classes directly from the JSON using this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

Here is the code snippet of User.Json method:

```
SeatBookingModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
userName= json['userName'];
userEmail= json['userEmail'];
 }
```

Happy Coding

Comment: The only reason you need to do an explicit conversion in this case is because you're using a `HashMap`.  If you used `LinkedHashMap` (or `Map`) instead, then no conversion would be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead if your object is deeper than one level:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> convertedData = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(yourData));
```