# Why does jsonDecode return a value that is uncastable to Map<String, Map<String, String>>?

Tags: json, dart

I'm programming a linguistic tool. I have a `languages.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "paradigms": {
        "test paradigm": {
            "1sg": "me",
            "2sg.gen": "lo",
            "3pl.acc": "tven"
        }
    }
}
```

(or, at least this is the relevant part)

Then, in my main dart file, i try to open and parse a part of the JSON file into a map:

```
void main() async {
    var langjson = jsonDecode(await File('resource/languages.json').readAsString());
    var paradigms = Map<String, Map<String, String>>.from(langjson['paradigms']);
}
```

Now dart tells me `_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>')`. Okay, I know if i just don't cast it, then `paradigms` will be that strange type anyway, but then I wouldn't be able to pass that to a certain class, which means i'd have to make the type of those members dynamic as well, and it just seems kind of ugly (I have tested this, it works). Isn't there some way to simply get a `Map` out of `jsonDecode`? I thought this is how it was supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_InternalLinkedHashMap` **is** a subtype of `Map` as you can read about in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861161/13250142). The issue with your code is that your specify incompatible values to store in the `Map`. You say `<String, String>`, when it can only be `<String, dynamic>`. Changing
`Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>` will solve your issue.

Additionally, as you can see in the linked answer, doing the `from` constructor to create a new `Map` is completely unnecessary as `jsonDecode` already returns the exact data type you're trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

The static return type of JSON deconding is `dynamic`, because it can be a map, list, number, string, boolean or `null`. For the same reason, *if* it is a map, it is a `Map<String, dynamic>` because the value *could* be any of the above.

In your case, you happen to know that the result is always a map, and that the values of that map are again maps, and the values of those maps are all strings. So, the data would match a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, but the JSON decoder doesn't know that ahead of time, so it builds a `Map<String, dynamic>` containing values that are `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Dart reifies generic types, so a `Map<String, dynamic>` containing only strings is *not* the same as a `Map<String, String>`. You can add a number value to the former, and not to the latter, so they are different.

To convert your data maps to something with type `Map<String, String>`, you can either do it eagerly:

```dart
var paradigms = langJson["paradigms"].map(value: (k, v) => MapEntry(k, v as String));
```

or lazily:

```dart
var paradigms = langJson["paradigms"].cast<String, String>();
```

The former checks all values immediately, and creates a new map object. The latter wraps the original map object and checks that the value is a `String` on each access.