# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' of 'function result'

Tags: list, flutter, dart, hashmap

I have looked at the following links before writing this question:

- [Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430061/unhandled-exception-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of)
- [Dart - how _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> convert to Map<String, dynamic>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845333/dart-how-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-convert-to-mapstring-dynami)
- https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-json-decode-type-internallinkedhashmap-dynamic-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-9d6b3e982b59

The code:

```
List data = [
    {
      "title" : "Particulate matter",
      "desc" : "The term used to describe a mixture of solid particles and liquid droplets found in the air",
      "amt" : 500,
      "diseases" : "Particulate matter is responsible for asthma in many people. Also, a topic dermatitis, allergic rhinitisare diseases that can be caused by this",
      "precaution" : "Switching to cleaner appliances and reducing the amount of smoking will surely ensure less exposureof particulate matter in the environment",
      "image" : 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3668372/pexels-photo-3668372.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260',
      "color" : Color(0xFF6E7E5D).withOpacity(.3)
    },
// loads of data in this structure
];

// the line of error
Map indexedData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(data[index]);
```

I simply don't know why the error exists so please help me out. Thank You!

EDIT: I can change the data to a limit if that helps solve the problem

Comment: How about actual code instead of broken meta-code?

Comment: I have updated it with the actual data, please check it

Comment: And what's in index?  zero I hope.

Comment: its actually under a `ListView.builder`, I can add it into the question if you want

Comment: What line is that error pointing to?  It appears not to be possible by anything you are showing.

Comment: Oh yes, it might be a bad way you've created your builder function.  Show that.

Comment: I have updated the code, please look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List data = [
    {
      "title": "Particulate matter",
      "desc":
          "The term used to describe a mixture of solid particles and liquid droplets found in the air",
      "amt": 500,
      "diseases":
          "Particulate matter is responsible for asthma in many people. Also, a topic dermatitis, allergic rhinitisare diseases that can be caused by this",
      "precaution":
          "Switching to cleaner appliances and reducing the amount of smoking will surely ensure less exposureof particulate matter in the environment",
      "image":
          'https://images.pexels.com/photos/3668372/pexels-photo-3668372.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260',
      "color": Color(0xFF6E7E5D).withOpacity(.3),
    },
  ];

  Map<String, dynamic> indexedData = {};

  data.forEach((mapElement) {
    Map map = mapElement as Map;
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      indexedData[key] = value;
    });
  });

print(indexedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the type like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> indexedData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(data[index]);
```