# Can't convert _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> to Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from `cloud_firestore`.

```
void _getData(){
    final getData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(id)
        .get();
    Map<String, dynamic> d = getData.data()!;

    for (dynamic i in d["tags"]) {
       .......
    }
}
```

But when `_getData()` is called, an error occurs at `for (dynamic i in d["tags"])` .

```
 _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847275/17831351) and changed my code.

`Map<String, dynamic> d = getData.data()!;`

to

`Map<String, dynamic> d = Map<String, dynamic>.from(getData.data()!);`

But the error never be fixed.

I don't want waste time with useless `_InternalLinkedHashMap`.

## RunTimeType print

```
print("type: " + d["tags"].runtimeType.toString());
```

output

```
I/flutter (18762): type: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```

Comment: It seems like `d["tags"]` is a map. Try `print(d["tags"].runtimeType);` before the for loop to see what type it is.

Comment: It was `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`. `Map<String, dynamic>.from` does not have meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error origin. when the specific document was broken, this error occurs.

In my case, I thought database was like this:

```
tags (array)
 |- tag1 (map)
     |- user (String)
     |- date (Timestamp)
 |- tag2 (map)
     |- user (String)
     |- date (Timestamp)
 ...
```

However the database was actually this:

```
tags (array)
 |- user (String)
 |- date (Timestamp)
```